# Dynamically creating a widget out of a long List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List`

```
var notesList = [
    {
      "title": "Personal",
      "body": "Notes related to personal life",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "Shopping list",
          "body": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "Groceries",
              "body": "Apples, Oranges, Bananas",
              "children": "",
            },
            {
              "title": "Amazon",
              "body": "CD-player, Quadcopter motor, Whiteboard marker",
              "children": null,
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          "title": "App ideas",
          "body": "App ideas for the future",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "Food recipes",
              "body": "A better way to make foods.",
              "children": null,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

And need a way to make the data into some kind of widget (any will do as long as it displays the data). Of course, the widget cannot just be for this list but for any kind of similar `List`.

The problem is not knowing if a certain item contains more `children` and then creating more widgets if it does. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this, firstly, You need to flatten the List of the given objects, Once the List is flattened you can then use this code to make a List view out of it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  dynamic notesList = [
    {
      "title": "Personal",
      "body": "Notes related to personal life",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "Shopping list",
          "body": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "Groceries",
              "body": "Apples, Oranges, Bananas",
              "children": "",
            },
            {
              "title": "Amazon",
              "body": "CD-player, Quadcopter motor, Whiteboard marker",
              "children": null,
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          "title": "App ideas",
          "body": "App ideas for the future",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "Food recipes",
              "body": "A better way to make foods.",
              "children": null,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
  ];

  List flatList = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    flatList = getFlatList(notesList);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(flatList[index]["title"]),
            subtitle: Text(flatList[index]["body"]),
          );
        },
        itemCount: flatList.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  static List getFlatList(List list) {
    List internalList = new List();
    list.forEach((item) {
      if (item["children"] is List) {
        internalList.addAll(getFlatList(item["children"]));
        internalList.add(item);
      } else {
        internalList.add(item);
      }
    });
    return internalList;
  }
}
```

The `getFlatList(List list)` method will take any List and convert it into a FlatList as required. The above code will give you results like this.

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for recursion. Something like the following wildly unsafe, untyped, and untested pseudoDart:

```dart
class ReKids extends StatelessWidget {
  ReKids(this.notes, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final notes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: notes.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
          var note = notes[idx];

          return ListTile(
            title: Text(note['title']),
            subtitle: ReKids(note['children']),
          );
        });
  }
}
```